# using DevicePolicyManager.setStatusBarDisabled crashed on Android5.0

Tags: android, android-statusbar, device-policy-manager

I'm creating a Device owner app for students,and need to disable statusbar, i have already my app to the Device owner app.
using other method of DevicePolicyManager.it ran successfully.
but when i use setStatusBarDisabled.it told no such method

```
05-27 14:08:19.164: E/AndroidRuntime(8066): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setStatusBarDisabled(Landroid/content/ComponentName;Z)Z in class Landroid/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
```

is there any process i missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setStatusBarDisabled is implemented in API level 23 (Marshmallow 6.0) and not 21/22 (Lollipop 5.0.x)

You can find the documentation at this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setStatusBarDisabled(android.content.ComponentName,%20boolean)).